# Date and Time Issue at 24 'o clock in data set returns NA after POSIXct command

Tags: r

i have a time series Data with 10 Minutes difference when i try to convert to date and time type using `df$Time1 <- dmy_hm(df$Time, tz="Asia/Calcutta")[image]

it returns NA at 24 o Clock time interval as you can see i have tried with `df$Time1 <- dmy_hm(df$Time, tz="Asia/Calcutta")`and `df$Time1 = as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M")` Please do guide me on this i am clueless whats happening at 02-07-16 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` which can take multiple formats

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(df$Time, c('dmy_HM', 'dmy'))
#[1] "2016-07-01 23:30:00 UTC" "2016-07-01 23:40:00 UTC"
#[3] "2016-07-01 23:50:00 UTC" "2016-07-02 00:00:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Time =  c("01-07-16 23:30", "01-07-16 23:40", "01-07-16 23:50",
        "02-07-16"))
```